# How to send multiple words in a curl post message

Tags: bash, curl

I am using below code to Post a curl command. But it is not taking any space or line-break as message input.

I tried with `%20` and other answers that is already in SO regarding this problem. None is working. It is giving error as

> "$error":"Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value\n

```
line="abc def"

curl  --user "USER":"Password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"message":"'${line}'"}}' --url http://${host}:${port}${REST_URL}
```

Comment: Can you provide feedback on the solution below? and mark the answer accepted if it solves your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a an unnecessary extra close brace `}` for your data segment. Also, the  variables in the middle of the `data` argument should be quoted. Also double-quote your `--url` string to prevent word-splitting by the shell.

```
curl  --user "USER":"Password" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-X POST -d '{"message":"'"${line}"'"}' \
--url "http://${host}:${port}${REST_URL}"
```